# Why is Session null in programmatically instantiated controller?

Tags: c#, .net, session, model-view-controller

In my HomeController when a particular action is called, I can see when debugging that the Session is there. However when the HomeController action instantiates another controller programmatically and accesses a property on it, that property tries to access the session and it is null.

Something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult SomeAction()
    {
        // When debugging, I can break here and
        // see the Session in the Immediate Window

        var a = new AnotherController();
        var b = a.SomeProperty;
    }
}

public class AnotherController : Controller
{
    public object SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            // Session is null here
            return Session["MyProperty"];
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Not sure if this is important, but forgot to mention that SomeAction is called via ajax. Since the Session is available in that action though, I wouldn't think this is relevant.

Comment: because ASP.NET MVC does more than just instantiating a controller - it sets the controller instance up with context giving access to session, request etc.

Comment: @Igor So what would you suggest I do?

Comment: create another class (non-controller) with the property (possibly static) where you use: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyProperty"]` and use that class in `SomeAction`.

Comment: You have got entirely the wrong idea. Controllers are never created in your own code with `new AnotherController()`.  Controllers are only created as part of a request's lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public PartialViewResult SomeAction()
  {
    // When debugging, I can break here and
    // see the Session in the Immediate Window
    var b = SessionHelper.SomeProperty;
  }
}

public class SessionHelper
{
  public static object SomeProperty
  {
    get
    {
      return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MyProperty"];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to create controller "by hands". You should refactor your code to avoid this. Move properties to service and inject it. Maybe you need to create custom [controller factory](http://develoq.net/2010/custom-controller-factory-in-asp-net-mvc/).

Comment: That would be a little overkill for this project but +1 for the link... might come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Session, you might be able to get it anywhere. YOu don't need to instantiate another controller to read it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult SomeAction()
    {
        //you can access the session anywhere
        var s = Session["MyProperty"] as YourTypeHere;
    }
}
```

You also can create a static class to hold a const string that represents the Session's name.